# Join two file data in pig to the output in a desired format

Tags: apache-pig

File 1 has the data:

```
Name ID 
-------
Mark 1
Gary 2
Robert 3
```

File 2 has the data:

```
ID  result
----------
1   success
2   Fail 
3   success
```

I loaded the data into two variables `a` & `b` now I want to join the data in based on ID for which result is success. I am able to join but I am getting the data in an improper format.

```
a = load '/file1' as (Name:chararray,ID:int);
b = load '/file2' as (ID:int,result:chararray);
c = join a by a2, b by b1;
```

When I dump c I am getting the output in the format of **(name,id,id,result)**... How I need join `a` & `b` such that I can get the output in the format of ***(name,id,result)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  What you have to do is project the fields that you want to keep using a `FOREACH`.  You can do something like this:

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE a::Name as Name, a::ID as ID, b::result as result ;
```

Comment: Yea. I did in that way. but I want to join the two files and get the id's which are success. We can't do join like that (name, id, result) ?

Comment: Well, you are getting the ids which are successes.  The issue is that they have two `ID` fields, when it makes more sense that the two `ID`s be merged into one.  The reason why it keeps both the `ID`s after the join is so that the output of the `inner join` (which is what you are doing), follows the same output as an `outer join`. See this [chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/2336149).

Comment: Ok. For this example ...Even if we do inner or outer join the output will be the same.

Comment: For the sample yes. Since there are no `ID`s that are unique to either File 1 or File 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter b before joining.

```
a = load '/file1' as (Name:chararray,ID:int);
b = load '/file2' as (ID:int,result:chararray);
z = FILTER b BY b2 == 'success';
```

Then join a and z.
    c = join a by a2, z by b1;

Later you need to do something as mentioned by @m2ert in previous answer.